# Ocultar uma div e mostrar outra ao clicar em um button usando javascript somente

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando fazer um quiz e quero que apareça uma pergunta de cada vez. Eu usei a propriedade css `display: none;` para ocultar, e criei uma função em javascript que recebe como parâmetro o id da div que tem que ser mostrada. Ao clicar no `button` Start é mostrada a primeira pergunta. Daí eu chamo a função novamente ao clicar no `button` Submit para mostrar a próxima pergunta, porém ela não aparece.

Ps: Quero usar apenas javascript

```js
function show_question (n) {
 //Esconde o button start
 document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
 //Mostrar a pergunta
 document.getElementById(n).style.display = 'inline'; 

}
```

```css
.question_form {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
 <main>
<button id="start" onclick="show_question('q1')">Start</button>
<div class="question_form" id="q1">
 <form id="question1">
  <h3>1. Which tag should used to represent the "header" of a document?</h3>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">head</li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">header</li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">heading</li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="d">main</li>
  </ul>  
  <button type="submit" id="btn-salvar" onclick="show_question('q2')">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div class="question_form" id="q2">
 <form id="quetion2">
  <h3>2. Which the following is a NOT feature of HTML?<h3>
   <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="a">New Media Elements</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="b">Form Input Types</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c">Local Storage</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="d">Cookies</li>
   </ul>  
   <button id="submit" onclick="show_question('q3')">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div class="question_form" id="q3">
 <form id="question3">
  <h3>3. Which element is the most appropriate to wrap around each blog post on a page?</h3>
   <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="a">section</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="b">post</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c">article</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="d">main</li>
   </ul>
   <button id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como os botões estão dentro de um formulário, ao executarem a ação do evento `onClick` sua página será recarregada, por isso a sensação de que a função `show_question` não está funcionando.

Como o primeiro botão não está em nenhum formulário, ele não faz isso, diferente dos demais.

Para resolver esse problema, basta fazer o que foi mencionado pelo `@FrancinaldoPortela` e deixar os seus eventos assim:

> ```
> onclick = "show_question( 'qID' ) ; return false ;"
> ```

De qualquer forma, para executar seu programa, basta ter um único botão, vou dar um exemplo e como ficaria abaixo, para você ter uma ideia e desenvolver em cima dela.

```
<html>
    <style>
    .question_form {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        var count = 0;

        function show_question () {
            if(count === 0) {
                document.getElementById('q' + ++count).style.display = 'block'; 
                document.getElementById('sendButton').innerText = 'Submit';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('q' + count).style.display = 'none'; 
                document.getElementById('q' + ++count).style.display = 'block'; 

                if(document.getElementById('q' + (count+1)) === null) {
                    // AQUI VOCÊ FAZ ALGUMA COISA QUANDO ACABAREM AS PERGUNTAS

                    document.getElementById('q' + count).style.display = 'none'; 
                    document.getElementById('sendButton').innerText = 'Start';
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
<main>

    <div class="question_form" id="q1">
        <form id="question1">
            <h3>1. Which tag should used to represent the "header" of a document?</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">head</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">header</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">heading</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="d">main</li>
            </ul>       
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="question_form" id="q2">
        <form id="quetion2">
      <h3>2. Which the following is a NOT feature of HTML?</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="a">New Media Elements</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="b">Form Input Types</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c">Local Storage</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="d">Cookies</li>
                </ul>       
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="question_form" id="q3">
        <form id="question3">
            <h3>3. Which element is the most appropriate to wrap around each blog post on a page?</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="a">section</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="b">post</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c">article</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="d">main</li>
                </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button id="sendButton" onclick="show_question();">Start</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o formulario esta sendo enviado, daí a tela ta atualizando. Você só precisa colocar um "preventDefault()" ou "return false" na chamada da função.

```
onclick="show_question('q2'); return false;"
```

ocultando as outras divs:

```
function show_question (n) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('question_form');
        for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
           ele[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    //Esconde o button start
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
    //Mostrar a pergunta
    document.getElementById(n).style.display = 'inline'; 

}
```

Comment: E como eu faço para esconder  a div anterior?

Comment: vc só precisa ocultar todas outras divs com a classe 'question_form' antes de mostrar questao. Atualizei a resposta.